# Problems to get the difference of days between two days with queryDsl on Oracle 11

Tags: java, sql, oracle, querydsl

I´m making a query with queryDsl.

I used this to create a BooleanExpresion

```
public BooleanBuilder getPredicate(BooleanBuilder pBuilderBusquePerso){

int dias = 30;

QEntity1 qEntity = QEntity1.entity;

pBuilderBusquePerso = pBuilderBusquePerso.and(qEntity.date1 != null
? (SQLExpressions.datediff(DatePart.day, qEntity.date2, qEntity.date1).lt(dias) ) :null );

return pBuilderBusquePerso;
}
```

And in another procedure I call and execute this as:

```
BooleanBuilder pBuilderBusquePerso = new BooleanBuilder();

Predicate filter =getPredicate(pBuilderBusquePerso);

Page<Entity> iLista = myRepository.findAll(getMyPredicate(usr, filter, tipoListado, null, estados), paginacion);
```

So the sql query result is:

```
select table1 ta1
......
exists (
select 1 
from
table2 ta2
where
   ta1.inv_id=ta2.inv_id 
 and diff_days(ta1.inv_exp_date, ta2.exp_date)<?
)
```

Giving the following error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "DIFF_DAYS":  invalid identifier

So the querysql translation for the ddbb oracle is wrong. Is there a way to translate from queryDsl to oracle functions? What should I need?

I also tried with DATETRUNC

```
pBuilderBusquePerso = pBuilderBusquePerso.and(qEntity.date1 != null
? (SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qEntity.date1).castToNum(Integer.class).subtract(SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qEntity.date2).castToNum(Integer.class))).lt(dias) :null );




exists (
select 1 
from
table2 ta2
 where
  ta1.inv_id=ta2.inv_id 
   and cast(trunc_day(ta2.exp_date) as number(10,0))-cast(trunc_day(ta1.inv_exp_date) as number(10,0))<?
```

Giving a similar error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "TRUNC_DAY":  invalid identifier

And addDays

```
pBuilderBusquePerso = pBuilderBusquePerso.and(qEntity.date1 != null
? ((SQLExpressions.addDays(qEntity.date2, dias)).after(qEntity.date1)):null );


exists (
select 1 
from
table2 ta2
where
  ta1.inv_id=ta2.inv_id 
   and add_days(ta1.inv_exp_date, ?)>ta1.exp_date
)
```

Giving another similar error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "ADD_DAYS":   invalid identifier

I was trying to follow this test to build my query
https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17765673/

Thanks in advance.

Edit: this is the full error trace.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:231)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
.....................


......................
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)

......................
......................
......................

(And here comes the ORA error)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "TRUNC_DAY": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)

.....
```

Comment: None of those functions exist in oracle.

Comment: Well I Know that because It tried the query in the oracle sql Developer. But is there a way to translate that queryDsl expressions to oracle functions?

Comment: you might say something like DATE1-DATE2 that gives a numerical difference in days

Comment: With the second try I just used SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qEntity.date1).castToNum(Integer.class).subtract(SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qEntity.date2).castToNum(Integer.class))).lt(dias) :null          So I cast the result to number.

Comment: I also tried this : DateTimeExpression<Date> fechaFactura = SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qInvoices.invExpDate);
   DateTimeExpression<Date> fechaVencimientos = SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qInvoices.paymentData.any().expDate);     But this needs a cast to, I didnt find a way to get a numberExpresion.

Answer (score 2):

The `SQLExpressions` methods work only when used with SQL, not with JPA/JPQL queries. Querydsl JPA doesn't provide datediff out of the box, since JPA doesn't support it.

Comment: So with Querydsl what would be a solution to se the diff between two dates? Or to add days to a date and compare it with other date in queryDsl?

Comment: You can try creating a date_diff function in your OracleDialect and call that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the comments, it's not possible in Oracle. However, since you've tagged `java`: [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is excellent to calculate difference between 2 dates.

```
public int CalculateDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2) {
   return Days.daysBetween(date1, date2).getDays();
}
```

Comment: I know but, is there a way to use Joda-Time with QueryDsl?, my problem is to try to use queryDsl predicate with the SQLExpresions functionalities into Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Finally in my team, we just change the focus to solve the problem after realizing this is not possible to do by queryDsl, so we create a custom repository and then we execute a query to obtain the days, so we obtain the id`s from a table and then we use them to filter the results of other query made with querydsl.

I hope this helps.

```html
@Repository
public class MyRepositoryImpl implements MyRepository, InitializingBean  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    private QTable1 qTable1;
    private PathBuilder<Table1> path;
    private Querydsl querydsl;
    private JPASQLQuery sqlquery;
    private SQLTemplates templates;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        this.qTable1 =  QTable1.table1;
        this.path = new PathBuilder<Table1>(qTable1.getType(), qTable1.getMetadata());
        this.querydsl = new Querydsl(em, path);

        this.templates = new OracleTemplates();
        this.sqlquery = new JPASQLQuery(em, templates);
    }





    @Override
    public List<Long> findDiasFecha(String data1, int id ) {

         String myQuery =null;
         int dias;

         switch (id) {
            case 1:  dias = 30;
                    break;
            case 2:  dias = 60;
                     break;
            case 3:  dias = 90;
                     break;
            case 4:  dias = 120;
                     break;
                         //5 & 6 are for 180 days
            default: dias = 180;
                     break;
        }

         
             myQuery =" SELECT i1.invId  FROM Table1 i1 WHERE i1.invRecCif = :data1 and "+
                     " i1.invId IN "+
                     "   (SELECT i2.invId "+
                     "   FROM Table1 i2, "+
                     "     Table2 pd "+
                     "   WHERE pd.entrada.invId = i2.invId "+
                     "   and i1.invId = i2.invId "+
                     "   AND TRUNC(pd.expDate)-TRUNC(i2.invExpDate)<= :dias "+
                     "   )";
         

         Long diasL = new Long(dias);
         TypedQuery<Long> typedQuery = em.createQuery(myQuery , Long.class);
         typedQuery.setParameter("dias", (double) diasL);
         typedQuery.setParameter("data1", data1);

         List<Long> results = typedQuery.getResultList();

        return results;
        }


    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

not possible with JPQL, because the lack of date arithmetic. But it can be done by the use of JPASQLQuery with `OracleTemplates` for native Queries, see: http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/reference/html_single/#d0e431

```
final JPASQLQuery query = new JPASQLQuery(em, OracleTemplates.DEFAULT);
//without jpa use: com.querydsl.sql.oracle.OracleQuery
query.select(
        SQLExpressions.datediff(
            DatePart.day,
            SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qEntity.date1),
            SQLExpressions.datetrunc(DatePart.day, qEntity.date2)))
        .from(qEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided this so ...

```
    protected enum TypeCompare {
                                EQ,
                                GT,
                                GOE,
                                LT,
                                LOE
    }
    private final static String ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT = "dd.mm.yyyy";
```

...

```
    protected BooleanExpression dateCompare(DateTimePath<java.util.Date> dateTimePath, Date date, TypeCompare typeCompare) {
        StringTemplate dbDate = Expressions.stringTemplate("function('TRUNC', {0})", dateTimePath);
        StringTemplate compareDate = Expressions.stringTemplate("function('TO_DATE', {0}, {1})", DateUtils.formatRuDate(date), ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT);
        switch (typeCompare) {
            case EQ:
                return dbDate.eq(compareDate);
            case GT:
                return dbDate.gt(compareDate);
            case GOE:
                return dbDate.goe(compareDate);
            case LT:
                return dbDate.lt(compareDate);
            case LOE:
                return dbDate.loe(compareDate);
            default:
                return dbDate.eq(compareDate);
        }
    }
```

[QueryDSL JPA Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45499989/querydsl-jpa-functions)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a date_diff function in your ExtendedOracleDialect and call that e.g.

`registerFunction( "date_diff", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "?1-?2") );`

and call it like this

```
.and(Expressions.numberTemplate(Integer.class, "function('date_diff', {0}, {1})", datefield1, datefield2).eq(6))
```

[How to use a custom function in a jpa query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484199/how-to-use-a-custom-function-in-a-jpa-query)

Comment: Oracle does not support `DATE_DIFF`