# How to use a custom function in a jpa query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am new to Spring Jpa and Hibernate. I am trying to fetch data using a custom function from an Oracle db. I could define an entity along with its related service, implementation and repository. In addition, I created a new custom Oracle dialect by using `registerFunction` as you will see below.

So I have two questions:

1) In my Oracle db, the function sits under a different schema. Do I need to specify its schema? If so how? Or will hibernate find it automatically?

I will be asking my second question at the end of this post after providing my full stacktrace...

Here is my full stack trace:

**MyOracle10gDialect**

```
package blog;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;


public class MyOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public MyOracle10gDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("my_function", new StandardSQLFunction("my_function"));
    }

}
```

**application.properties**

```
...
spring.jpa.database-platform=blog.MyOracle10gDialect
...
```

**Entity:**

```
package blog.models;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "item", schema = "WOS_SOURCE")
public class WosItem {

    @Id
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String UT;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String TI;

    public String getUT() {
        return UT;
    }

    public void setUT(String UT) {
        this.UT = UT;
    }

    public String getTI() {
        return TI;
    }

    public void setTI(String TI) {
        this.TI = TI;
    }

    public WosItem(String UT, String TI) {
        this.UT = UT;
        this.TI = TI;
    }

    public WosItem() { }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "WosItem{" +
                "UT='" + UT + '\'' +
                ", TI='" + TI + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
package blog.services;

import blog.models.WosItem;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface WosItemService {

    List<WosItem> findAll();
    WosItem findById(String id);
    String find_ut(Long ut_seq);
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
package blog.services;

import blog.models.WosItem;
import blog.repositories.WosItemRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class WosItemServiceJpaImpl implements WosItemService {

    @Autowired
    private WosItemRepository wosItemRepository;

    @Override
    public List<WosItem> findAll() {
        return this.wosItemRepository.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public WosItem findById(String id) {
        return this.wosItemRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    @Override
    public String find_ut(Long ut_seq) {
        return this.wosItemRepository.find_ut();
    }
}
```

**Repository:**

```
package blog.repositories;

import blog.models.WosItem;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;


@Repository
public interface WosItemRepository extends JpaRepository<WosItem, String> {
    @Query("SELECT function('my_function', input) FROM WosItem wos");
    String find_ut();
}
```

So in my Oracle db I can use this function as shown below:

```
select other_schema.my_function(aa.input) from my_schema.TABLE aa;
```

For ex. say aa.input is `332708100009` then it returns `000332708100009`

As for my second question:

2) How can I carry out this process in jpa? I am aware that my repository is not correct at all. I get an error like "Annotations are not allowed here". I could not find a way to remedy this.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT ON THROWN EXCEPTION:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
 \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (my_function)'
    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'my_function' {originalText=my_function}
    \-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'
       \-[NAMED_PARAM] ParameterNode: '?' {name=ut_seq, expectedType=null}
```

Comment: Annotations don't require to be ended with `;`. Just remove that.

Comment: Thanks! @M.Deinum Now I have an error as updated above. How can I invoke the input value in my repository?

Comment: You don't seem to have an `input` column on `WosItem`. Can you post your exact code without trivialising it?

Comment: Please limit question to one question at a time. If you have multiple questions make them multiple posts.
Also, once a problem is solved, accept the correct and upvote all helpful answer. 
Please do not edit the question to ask a different question. Again, just create a new question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately if you want to use the JPA 2.1 feature of the custom `function` call in your `Select` statement then you will need to perform some additional actions before you can use it.

When you use it in your `where` statement then it works without any additional actions, but as i wanted to use it for one of my projects inside the select just as you did then you would need to:

**1)** Extend the hibernate dialect and register your function(s):

```
package com.mypkg.dialect;

import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.StringType;

public class CustomOracle10gDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {

    public CustomOracle10gDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("my_function"
           , new StandardSQLFunction("my_function", new StringType()));
    }
}
```

**2)** Edit your `hibernate.dialect` property of your session factory to point to that custom implementation:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="com.mypkg.dialect.CustomOracle10gDialect"/>
```

**Update**

If the function needs to be called from a certain schema then this would be suggested:

```
registerFunction("my_function"
           , new StandardSQLFunction("schema.my_function", new StringType()));
```

Further reading -> [native function calls](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already done this. Please see my application properties code above. Now it seems that I cannot call my input value to be used in my repository.

Comment: have u tried adding explicit return type new StringType()? Sorry i completely missed the beginning of your question..

Comment: btw.. your WosItem does not seem to have an 'input' field or am i missing something?

Comment: Ah yes I was careless not adding StringType(). When adding that, code worked. As for your other warning, yes I was not sure to add it since it is not a column in my table. So I am a bit confused.

Comment: I see.. so basically your method should have a param find_ut(String input) and in your query you use :input in the function.  Anyway.. glad it is now working for you.

Comment: In addition, how can I explicitly state the schema including the function? Because, now I get the following error: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "my_function": invalid identifier...And here is the query Hibernate: select my_function(?) as col_0_0_ from TABLE.item wositem0_

Comment: I would try: registerFunction("my_function"
           , new StandardSQLFunction("other_schema.my_function", new StringType()));

Comment: or you can set a default schema which should be picked up by hibernate: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=schema

Comment: Many thanks @Maciej Kowalski ! your first suggestion (other_schema.my_function) worked very well. In addition, I added String find_ut(Long ut_seq); to my service and now it works!

Comment: Great! i have updated the answer for other users to know