# Spring Boot JPA function in query

Tags: sql, spring, jpa

I want to call a function in my query. For example:

```
SELECT myT.col1, myT.col2, myT.col3, fun_get_calculatedCol(myT.col4) as calcCol FROM myTable myT
```

In my **myTableRepository** i can do the following:

```
@Query("SELECT myT.col1, myT.col2, myT.col3 from MyTable myT")
List<MyTable> getCustomColumns();
```

but adding a function call to the statement does not work:

```
@Query("SELECT myT.col1, myT.col2, myT.col3, fun_get_calculatedCol(myT.col4) as calcCol from MyTable myT")
List<MyTable> getCustomColumns();
```

Is there a way to get it work in JPQL?

My error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
+-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'fun_get_calculatedCol' {originalText=fun_get_calculatedCol}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors? please post that if so

Comment: "does not work". LOL. That doesnt really tell people anything, at all.Maybe JPQL does not support some random SQL function "fun_get_calculated"? which it doesnt. JPQL != SQL.

Comment: JPQL is a query language on it's own. It is **not** SQL, so you can't use any native SQL features in JPQL.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in JPQL? I found a solution with NamedNativeQuery and SqlResultSetMapping, but that's too much code for just one more column. I am still learning, so pls help me if you know a solution, thanks :)

Comment: As any JPA documentation would tell you, JPQL allows you to use "FUNCTION({sql_function_name}, args)" to invoke SQL functions (replacing "sql_function_name" with the name of the function). Perhaps read some docs ...

Comment: @DN1 you're right. This has been already discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484199/how-to-use-a-custom-function-in-a-jpa-query

Answer (score 0):

You can define it as native query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT myT.col1, myT.col2, myT.col3, fun_get_calculatedCol(myT.col4) as calcCol from MyTable myT", nativeQuery = true)
List<MyTable> getCustomColumns();
```

Comment: I get the following exception: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name. In my myTable i have a "private static String calcCol" defined