# Spring boot repository for read-only data: @Query annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to create a basic repository so I can get my region's time zones as supported by Postgres.  I'm getting the error "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration."
How should I approach this?  Why am I not allowed to define a query here?

```
import com.me.model.PgTz;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
@Repository
public interface TzRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.Repository<PgTz,String>
{
    @Query("SELECT tz FROM PgTz tz WHERE tz.name STARTSWITH 'US/' OR tz.name STARTSWITH 'America/'");
    Iterable<PgTz> findPgTzByName(); 
}
```

Comment: Can you please include your imports as well?

Comment: Done.  Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a semicolon after `@Query()` declaration which is illegal in java. Removing it should fix compilation.

```
@Query("SELECT tz FROM PgTz i WHERE i.name STARTSWITH('US/') OR i.name STARTSWITH('America/')")
Iterable<PgTz> findPgTzByName();
```

See [Annotations Basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/basics.html)

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I really miss working in an office, a coworker would have spotted that right away.  You wouldn't happen to know why STARTING_WITH, StartingWith, IsStartingWith or StartsWith yield syntax errors?  I had to use LIKE which I try not to use out of personal preference.

Comment: @RickDeBay by default `@Query()` uses JQPL to interpret the query and it doesn't have `startwith` function. You can set `@Query('SELECT...', nativeQuery = true)` to use native SQL directly but AFAIK PostgresQL does not have `startwith` function either. If you use HIbernate as JPA provider you can register custom functions as explained in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42486291/4624905). But I personally don't think it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I think your already imported the persistence.query in repository so your getting error
Delete that import and then try