# Is there a QueryDSL representation of JSON_CONTAINS predicate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, querydsl, mysql-8.0

On my MySQL database (8.0.23), I have a JSON column that is [multi value indexed](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued).
I would like to use QueryDSL to query using the index with `JSON_CONTAINS`.
I have validated that the column is indexed properly and the index is being used when I run the query; for instance,

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM user u
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(u.alias,'$'), JSON_QUOTE('John'));
```

indicates the multi value index is being used as expected.

So far, I have attempted

```
Expressions.booleanTemplate("JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT({0}, '$'), JSON_QUOTE({1})) = 1", expression, str)
```

and have the `BooleanExpression` as the predicate to achieve the same using QueryDSL; please note that without the `= 1`, executing it would throw the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:748)
```

Indeed, the `= 1` seems like preventing the index from being used for the same query. For instance,

```
EXPLAIN SELECT *
FROM user u
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(u.alias,'$'), JSON_QUOTE('John')) = 1;
```

would indicate no index is being used. It was the same with `!= 0`, `IS TRUE` or `IS NOT FALSE`

Therefore, the problem I'm having is that with QueryDSL I have not found a way to have a `BooleanExpression` on `JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(u.alias,'$'), JSON_QUOTE('John'))` without the `= 1` at the end. However, MySQL seems like it's not using the multi value index when there is `= 1` at the end of the `JSON_CONTAINS`

I have attempted suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/68684997/18476687 but had no luck so far.

Would there be a way to represent `JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(u.alias,'$'), JSON_QUOTE('John'))` without the `= 1` on QueryDSL so that multi value index is being used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a hacky workaround for this that actually works pretty well. By extending the Hibernate dialect you can create custom HQL functions that return arbitrary SQL.

So you can define a dialect with a custom HQL function `custom_json_contains` like:

```java
public class CustomMySQL8Dialect extends MySQL8Dialect {
    public CustomMySQL8Dialect() {
        registerFunction("custom_json_contains", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(?1, ?2), JSON_QUOTE(?3)) AND 1"));
    }
}
```

Then you can use this method in a QueryDSL where clause (or HQL):

```java
public static <T> BooleanExpression jsonContains(Expression<T> expression, String path, String str) {
    return Expressions.booleanTemplate("CUSTOM_JSON_CONTAINS({0}, {1}, {2}) = 1", expression, path, str);
}
```

This will make Hibernate render the following SQL:

```sql
JSON_CONTAINS(JSON_EXTRACT(u.alias, '$'), JSON_QUOTE('John')) AND 1=1
```

The `= 1` is still there but at least now it doesn't do anything!